# React native version updating not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I tried to update my "React-native" version to 0.59.0 from 0.57.8, but it is not updating.

**react-native upgrade 0.59.0-rc.0** this command is using for updating, but after updating am getting the response as **Successfully upgraded this project to react-native v0.57.8**. Also, cross-check with the package file, it shows the old react-native version.

Comment: `react-native upgrade` is broken in versions before 0.59.0, so you'll have to do the update manually using the upgrade helper: https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/. From version 0.59.0 forward, you can use the upgrade tool again.

Comment: @Marcel Kalveram so you saying need to change all the files one by one manually

Comment: Yes, all the other approaches are quite error-prone.

Comment: Turn off the computer and turn it on.